# How do IaaS vendors ensure consistent performance of the vCPUs they sell across different hardware?

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtual-machines, cloud, cloud-computing

IaaS vendors like AWS sell cloud instances based on vCPUs. In principle, vCPUs within the same type of cloud instance should have similar single-core performance (excluding the issue of noisy neighbors). However, for the vendor, the CPUs in their data centers are bound to be diverse, with each CPU model having different single-core performance capabilities.

**So, how do they establish the correspondence between vCPUs on the cloud instance and the logical cores on the physical machine?**

For instance, if I purchase a cloud instance with 16 vCPUs, it might correspond to 14 CPU quotas on a newer machine with higher single-core performance, such as Icelake or SPR. On the other hand, it might require 18 CPU quotas on an older machine with lower single-core performance, like Cascade Lake. How is this ratio, such as 16-14 or 16-18, determined? Please note that the specific numbers mentioned here are just examples for illustration purposes.

Comment: There is no general answer possible. I’d assume that each vendor will have a different  approach and will for example only guarantee the lowest common denominator when there are different CPU generations, avoid the scenario completely by introducing new flavors and retiring legacy or differently. For Google cloud for example: *” Each machine series is associated with one or more CPU platforms. If there are multiple CPU platforms available for a machine type, you can select a minimum CPU platform for the VM.”* https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms

Comment: I think this assumption is flawed : *”In principle, vCPUs within the same type of cloud instance should have similar single-core performance”* - vCPU’s are an abstraction for resource allocation and not an absolute and objective value and the amount of performance they represent will most likely be different on different hardware. Four  vCPU is twice 2 vCPU on the same hardware but not when one VM runs on a completely different physical CPU generation / model / type